# Organize elements in a table with DOM - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

this code is to create a table

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
if ((lines > 0) && (columns> 0)) {
    var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
    var tr, td;
    for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
      tr = document.createElement("tr");
      for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        td = document.createElement("td");
        tr.appendChild(td);
      }
      tbody.appendChild(tr);
    }
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    document.body.appendChild(table);
```

like this image 1

[image]

`class Panel`and `function` to putAndShowEquipment

```
function Panel(id, line, column) {
  this.id = id;
  this.lines = line;
  this.columns = column;
  this.equipments = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < lines; i++{
      this.equipments[i] = [];
  }

}

Panel.prototype.putAndShowEquipment = function(line, column, equipment) {
  if ((line >= 0) && (line < this.lines) 
     && (column >= 0) && (column < this.columns) 
     && ((equipament === void 0) || (equipament instanceof Equipament))) {
    this.equipaments[line][column] = equipament;
    if (equipament) {
      equipament.show(this.cell(line, column));
    } else {
      (new View()).show(this.cell(line, column));
    }
  }
  return this;
}
```

and I wanna made like this image 2

[image]

and I can made, if I do

```
//panel with 4 lines and 4 columns to 16 equipments
(new Panel("panel",4,4))
.putAndShowEquipment (0, 0, new Equipament())
.putAndShowEquipment (0, 1, new Equipament())
.putAndShowEquipment (1, 0, new Equipament())
.putAndShowEquipment (1, 1, new Equipament())
.putAndShowEquipment (2, 0, new Equipament())
.putAndShowEquipment (2, 1, new Equipament())
 ...
 ;
```

but I try to create the `lines` and `columns` using `for` and put the equipaments, **I think maybe have restriction when is four column, change to another line**, I have all ready, now is only a **matter of calculations**

```
//four lines
for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
 //four columns
  for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    //if column is four
    if (j === 4) {
      //change line
     //this.equipaments.lenght = 16 equipments
      panel.putAndShowEquipment(i + 1, j, this.equipaments[i]);
    } else {
      panel.putAndShowEquipment(i, j, this.equipaments[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: A little hard to understand, but if there are 4 columns, then `j` will never equal `4` inside the loop, because the loop will have stopped. Not sure why you need the `if` statement at all, but then we don't know what the value of `this` is in your last code block. Seems like it should just be `panel.putAndShowEquipment(i, j, /* ???? */)` but there's not enough info to know where the 3rd argument should come from.

Comment: Also, in the `putAndShowEquipment` method, it seems like `(line < this.columns)` should be `(line < this.lines)`, but again, not enough info.

Comment: @squint, thanks, i see the error, I edit the `(line < this.lines)`  and the equipments came form `this.equipments = [];` in `class Panel` ,  I don´t put  the other because i think is not neccessary

Comment: @squint, I edit the question adding more code

Comment: I need to implement to get **calculation to insert equipment in table in insertion order**, like show in **image 2**

Comment: So if in the last code block, `this.equipaments[i]` is fetching elements from an Array with an `.length` of `16`, then it would seem like you'd just get rid of the `if` statement in the loop, and simply do `panel.putAndShowEquipment(i, j, this.equipaments[(i * 4) + j]);`. The `(i * 4) + j` will give you an ordered sequence of `0` through `15`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your updated question, it seems that you simply need to convert a flat Array into a rectangular one by passing each member of the flat `this.equipaments` Array into the constructor.

If that's the case, and given that the number of `lines * columns` will be equal to the `this.equipaments.length`, then instead of an `if` statement, all you'd need is to calculate the index from `i` and `j`.

```
// lines * columns === this.equipaments.length

for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    panel.putAndShowEquipment(i + 1, j, this.equipaments[(i * columns) + j]);
  }
}
```

Because there are an equal number of columns per lines, we multiply the current line number by the total number of columns and then add the current column number.

Comment: I use `lines * columns === this.equipaments.length` doesn´t work and I use `var lines=this.equipments.length;` and `var columns=this.equipments.length` it´s work, but the same `panel` show the rest `lines` and `columns` empty, is anyway to **show only rows and columns filled with equipments**

Comment: @RenataPSouza: `lines * columns === this.equipaments.length` was in a comment just to note that the number of `lines` multiplied by the number of `columns` should be equal to the `.length` of the array. Just remove it. Why is `lines` and `columns` set to the same length of the Array? If you have `this.equipaments.length` items to put in, then `lines` and `columns` should be factors of the `.length`.